# ImageResizer not working after deployment to IIS7.5 integrated mode, ashx style url works

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, imageresizer

I'm using ImageResize.net in an MVC3 site.

It works correctly on my dev machine (using iis7.5 integrated mode) and does not require the use of `ashx` extension for resized images.

I've deployed to iis7.5 (integrated) on a new provisioned VM.  I have no errors there but the images are not resized.

Testing the images urls in another browser tab shows that I **can get resized images** if I include the `ashx` extension.

I've double-checked that the target site is using Integrated mode.

Any ideas on where else to look to figure this out?

Comment: Presently no resolution.  In the meantime I've had to provision another server -- believing that I had done this before without any ImageResizer problems on a WIN2012 box.  I provisioned a WIN2012 VM with IIS8 and deployed my site -- NO PROBLEM.  Hmmm.

Comment: What version of windows is on the troublesome server? And what v. of ImageResizer are you running? A gist of the diagnostics page is required for official help.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist Troublesome server is WIN2K8 R2.  [WIN2K8 Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5637823)  Server thats acts as expected is WIN2012 IIS8.  [WIN2012 Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5637871)

Comment: @ComputerLinguist resizer version is 3.3.1.526

Comment: Same code on both? There are ways to 'break' the extension-less syntax through third-party code.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist yes, same code on both systems.  I'm using `MSDEPLOY` so it's just a publish in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Probably won't help you since my problem was not being able to get the resized versions *at all*, with or without the ashx extension, but just in case. If the `imagecache` directory does not exist in your application folder, create it, and then make sure IIS_Users has modify access in the Security tab of the folder's properties.

**EDIT**

Oh. I forgot about the [MvcRoutingShim](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/mvcroutingshim). Make sure you have that installed.

Comment: `MvcRoutingShim` seems to be installed and present on both systems.  There is not an `imagecache` folder on either system.